определите вид придаточного!
в общем я вообще запуталась в этих видах придаточных предложений.
«время такое, что людям беседовать некогда»
нужно определить вид придаточного, перебрала все, но есть свои нюансы.
если говорить про изъяснительное, то мы не можем задать вопрос косвенного падежа(это написано в учебнике 9 класса) и здесь нет слов, имеющих значение речи, мысли, чувства.
если говорить про определительное, то мы тоже не можем поставить правильный вопрос, к тому же «такое» является не определением, а является частью составного именного сказуемого. и «что» не является союзным словом.
если говорить про местоименно определительное, то опять же такие «что» не является союзным словом.
и что это за придаточное такое? формулировка и ответ нужен на уровне 9 класса, я пока не учусь в вузе, а всего лишь пытаюсь разобраться и углубиться в эту тему на уровне школьной программы.
и не говорите мне, что это придаточное сказуемное, мне нужен вид придаточного по другой классификации(определительные, изъяснительные и обстоятельственные.

РАЗБОР ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ (определение вида придаточного).
Для сравнения разберем еще некоторые предложения.
(1) Время такое, что людям беседовать некогда.
Местоименно-определительное придаточное двойного значения (определение + следствие); местоименно-союзная связь: ТАКОЕ – союз ЧТО; местоимение (указательное и определяемое слово) в главном предложении является сказуемым.
(2) Время такое, когда людям беседовать некогда.
Местоименно-определительное придаточное; местоименная связь: ТАКОЕ – ПРИ КОТОРОМ (= КОГДА); местоимение (указательное слово) в главном предложении является сказуемым.
(3)  Мы живем в такое время, что людям беседовать некогда.
Определительное придаточное двойного значения (определение + следствие); местоименно-союзная связь: ТАКОЕ время – ЧТО); в главном предложении местоимение (указательное слово) является определением, относится к опорному существительному время; в придаточном союз со значением следствия ЧТО.
(4) Мы живем в такое время, когда людям беседовать некогда.
Определительное придаточное; местоименная связь: ТАКОЕ время – ПРИ КОТОРОМ (= КОГДА); в главном предложении местоимение (указательное слово) является определением, относится к опорному существительному время; в придаточном союз со значением следствия ЧТО.
Пояснение
При разборе используем базовую школьную грамматику, дополненную некоторыми сведениями из вузовской структурной грамматики.

Все СПП (сложноподчиненные предложения) можно разделить на две группы: нерасчлененные (обычно местоименная связь) и расчлененные (обычно союзная связь).

Это важно понять. В первой группе мы не можем разделить предложение на две самостоятельные части (совсем убрать придаточное), но это возможно сделать для предложений второй группы.
В первой группе связь взаимообусловленная, а во второй группе чисто подчинительная (союз как показатель подчинения относится  к придаточному). К первой группе относятся: определительные и местоименно-определительные придаточные, а также изъяснительные; ко второй группе — большинство обстоятельственных придаточных.

Все приведенные варианты предложений являются СПП нерасчлененного вида с союзной или местоименно-союзной (двойной) связью.

Придаточные определительные предложения отвечают на вопрос КАКОЙ? и определяют опорное слово с предметным значением (обычно существительное), находящееся в главном предложении.


В СПП с придаточными определительными обычно используются указательные слова ТОТ, ТАКОЙ и союзные слова КАКОЙ, КОТОРЫЙ. Союзное слово КОТОРЫЙ часто заменяется в зависимости от смысла на союзные слова ГДЕ, КОГДА, ОТКУДА, например: Это дом, в котором мы жили раньше. – Это дом, где мы жили раньше.

В местоименно-определительных придаточных указательные слова одновременно являются и определяемыми (опорными) словами.
В главном предложении указательные слова играют роль подлежащего, сказуемого или дополнения, соответственно условно различаются три вида придаточных предложений.

О правильном вопросе для местоименно-определительных придаточных. Вопрос: какое именно время?
Можно посмотреть в таблице


ЛИТЕРАТУРА
Литневская, Русский язык: краткий теоретический курс, стр. 90
У Литневской даются также пояснения о школьных видах классификации СПП для различных уровней (учебных комплексов). Эта тема изучается в 9-м классе. Более распространённой в практике школьного и довузовского преподавания является классификация, принятая в комплексах 1 и 3.
Можно дополнительно посмотреть: Виды сложноподчиненных предложений

благодарю за помощь,очень доходчиво)

Спасибо!  А мне понравился ваш вопрос, такие темы всем интересны. .Заходите к нам чаще.

Sharon, так как вы рассматриваете это предложение? Местоименно- определительное или определительное?

Так я же написала:  "Время такое, что людям беседовать некогда". Местоименно-определительное придаточное двойного значения (определение + следствие);  А что, есть сомнения?  Литневская  выделяет местоименно-определительные придаточные в группе определительных. Но если очень хочется обобщить  и разделить придаточные  на три темы, то  отнесите его  к определительным.

Дополнение к ответу
О позиции неразличения двух видов связи (местоименно-определительной и местоименно-союзной)

Для определительных и местоименно-определительных СПП  возможны две местоименные пары: (1) тот — который и (2) такой — который. Первый вариант называется просто выделительным, а второй качественно-типизирующим, то есть не просто выделяющим, но и дающим качественную характеристику.

И здесь есть интересный момент, когда возникает позиция неразличения  двух видов предложений с местоимением ЧТО.


Пример из учебника (для определительных СПП): Он такой человек, что пойдет на все ради денег. Это определительно-союзная связь, ЧТО — союз следствия.
Подберем парный вариант: Есть такие люди, что (= которые) могут пойти на все ради денег. Это уже определительная связь, и увидеть здесь разницу достаточно сложно.

Два варианта

Время  такое, что людям беседовать некогда. Местоименно-определительное придаточное с местоименно-союзной связью.
Время (бывает) такое, что (= при котором, когда) людям беседовать некогда. Местоименно-определительное (типизирующее) придаточное с местоименной связью.
Различить сложно, здесь потенциальная и реализованная возможности совпадают. Можно выбрать первый вариант, но следует помнить, что второй тоже возможен.
