придаточные предложения
совсем не понимаю разницу между изъяснительными и местоименно-определительными придаточными…
да, конечно, понятное дело, что местоименно определительные придаточные будут зависеть от местоимения, но бывают же случаи когда можно задать два вопроса
я поместил в этой книге только то(что?/какое именно?), что относилось к пребыванию Печорина на Кавказе
какой из двух вопросов будет верным?
по поводу союзов и союзных слов тоже не поняла, ведь союзы тоже могут быть в местоименно-определительных предложениях (я уже задавала этот вопрос,там было что-то по типу «время было такое, что люди не разговаривали» условно. «что» будет союзом, но не смотря на это придаточное будет местоименно определительным.
моя учительница по русскому объяснила разницу между данными типами придаточных так:
все зависит от глагола, к которому относится придаточное.(глаголы чувств,речи,эмоций,мысли) или же это может быть существительное или прилагательное. во всех этих случаях будет изъяснительное, в других же местоименно определительное.
я понимаю еще предложения, где местоимение выступает в роли сказуемого или подлежащего, там действительно понятно, что это местоименно определительное, но в предложениях, где местоимение является дополнением возникают вопросы…

Вопросы возникают по поводу обычного форматирования текста. Вы не на телеграфном аппарате его набирали?

ну что вы тут ко мне все пристали со своим оформлением??спешила очень сильно,писала после урока.какие ко мне могут быть претензии, если я только учусь.если вам нечего ответить на мой вопрос,то можете вообще ничего не писать.


Местоименно-определительное придаточное

Я поместил в этой книге только то, что относилось к пребыванию Печорина на Кавказе.
Поместить (что?) — переходный глагол. Это местоименно-определительное придаточное (дается характеристика  сюжетной линии). Это не ментальный глагол.
Сравнить  с определительным придаточным: Я поместил в этой книге только те материалы, что (= которые) относилось к пребыванию Печорина на Кавказе.
ПРИЗНАКИ:  местоименная пара то — что; местоимение ТО нельзя убрать из главного предложения; ЧТО является ПОДЛЕЖАЩИМ в придаточном; глагол управляет местоимением (поместил что?), а к придаточному задается вопрос от местоимения: что именно?

Изъяснительное придаточное со сходным содержанием.

Я решил, что в книге нужно разместить материалы только о  пребывании Печорина на Кавказе.
Решил (что?) — ментальный опорный глагол со значением желания, воли, усилий, от него задается вопрос к придаточному; указательное слово невозможно; ЧТО — союз, служебное слово перед изъяснительной частью, можно преобразовать в БСП: Я решил: в книге нужно разместить материалы только о  пребывании Печорина на Кавказе.
Разбор похожей темы, в том числе  с союзным словом в роли дополнения, можно посмотреть здесь.

Сравним два вида придаточных с местоименной парой то — что:

(1) Я знаю то, что ты еще не успел узнать (местоименно-определительное, характеристика знания). Союзное слово ЧТО в качестве дополнения . Указательное слово обязательно, убрать его нельзя.
(2) Я знаю, что ты еще не успел узнать главного (изъяснительное, содержание знания). Обратим внимание: ЧТО — союз, но не союзное слово/дополнение. Дополнение там уже есть (главного). Указательное слово здесь запрещено (стилистическая ошибка).

вы указывали на союзные слова в местоименно-определьных придаточных. и тут, как я понимаю, есть нюансы. я уже задавала вопрос на данном форуме о придаточном в предложении «время такое,что людям беседовать некогда» здесь «что» является союзом,но тем не менее предложение местоименно-определительное,верно?

Да,  все верно. Здесь определяемым словом является местоимение-сказуемое, но связь не  чисто местоименная, а местоименно-союзная (союз следствия ЧТО). // Но ваш вопрос заставил меня задуматься и вспомнить один интересный момент из учебника Кустовой. Поэтом я дополню вопрос по этому предложению https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/482051/определите-вид-придаточного/482120#482120
